# Enviar un string como un fichero usando request en Node

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo un *String* y quiero convertirlo a un *stream* para enviarlo como si fuera un fichero a través del `multipart` de `request`.

Quiero hacerlo en el aire, sin generar el fichero en disco.

Estoy haciéndolo de ésta manera:

```
const stream = require("stream")

module.exports = function () {
        let readStream = new stream.PassThrough()
        readStream.end(new Buffer('<file data>'), () => {

            const options = {
                url: '<url>',
                method: 'POST',
                json: true,
                formData: {
                    file: readStream
                }
            };
            request(options, (error, res)=> {
                if(error) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
                }
            });
        })
    })
}
```

... y me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
{
    "code":"BadRequestError",
    "message":"MultipartParser.end(): stream ended unexpectedly: state = PART_DATA"
}
```

Comment: Y no se sirve hacer `formData: {  file : new Buffer('<file data>') }`?

Comment: O también `readStream.end(new Buffer('<file data>')).pipe(request.post('<url>'));`

Comment: El primero no hace nada. Y el segundo no me vale por que podrían ser varios ficheros...

Comment: Añadida una recompensa para que se animen a una solución, es una buena pregunta!

Comment: `var s = new stream.Readable();  s.push('texto o variable con el texto'); s.push(null);` Ver: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se me ocurren 2 formas:

### Sin stream

- Usando [`formData`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads) de `request` enviamos el `custom_file`.

```js
module.exports = function () {
  const options = {
      url: '<url>',
      method: 'POST',
      json: true,
      formData: {
        custom_file: {
          value: '<file data>',
          options: {
            filename: 'file.txt',
            contentType: 'text/plain'
          }
        }
      }
  };

  let req = request(options, (error, res)=> {
      if(error) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
      }
  })
}
```

### Con stream

- Usando [`Readable`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_new_stream_readable_options) creas un `stream` del `string`.

Ejemplo:

```js
const Readable = require('stream').Readable

module.exports = function () {

  //
  let stream = new Readable;
  stream._read = function noop() {};
  stream.push('<file data>');
  stream.push(null); // Indicamos fin del archivo (fin del stream)
  

  const options = {
      url: '<url>',
      method: 'POST',
      json: true,
      formData: {
        custom_file: {
          value: stream,
          options: {
            filename: 'file.txt',
            contentType: 'text/plain'
          }
        }
      }
  };
  
  let req = request(options, (error, res)=> {
      if(error) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(error))
      }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno lo que hace falta es cambiar el MIME type en el header.

```
const options = {
    headers: {
        "Content-Disposition":"attachment; filename=\"{filename}\""
    }
    url: '<url>',
    method: 'POST',
    json: true,
    formData: {
        file: readStream
    }
};
```